# MYSQL has gone away after inserting more than 100 000 values

Tags: mysql, wordpress

MYSQL has gone away after inserting more than 100 000 values.
I committed this problem when I was working with WordPress and MySQL. it is through an error when data had over up to 100k.

Edited : I didn't use indexing and each insert query was creating new db connection.

Comment: I see you are a new user. Did you know that you should choose one answer as accepted? For this you use the green bird icon next to the number between triangles to the left of the answer. You can also use the up triangle (upvote) on any answer to indicate that it was useful, or the down triangle (downvote) to indicate that it is counterproductive.

Comment: hey thanks to tell me but i did click on button but it is indicating "Vote Up requires 15 reputation" to me. so thats why i m unable to do click on any answer.

Comment: I guess it was the upward triangle. The correct button is a green bird that is below the downward triangle.

Comment: ohk Thanks to Help broda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try by increasing the following values in mysql ini file

```
max_allowed_packet = 64M

sort_buffer_size = 2M
net_buffer_length = 2M
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 64M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M
```

Comment: Thanks To all of you for Sharing my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing you call MySQL from PHP, you should split the data in smaller chunks. After more than thousand values or so a call to MySQL from PHP often timeouts.

Or, you should increase the timeout in PHP:

```
ini_set ('max_execution_time',    200); // seconds, default: 30
ini_set ('mysql.connect_timeout', 200); // seconds, default: 60
```

Comment: Thanks To all of you for Sharing my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by adding some configuration on the `php.ini` basic file.

```
upload_max_filesize = 2M // you can choose the size

max_execution_time = 60 // set execution time according to you
```

Comment: Thanks To all of you for Sharing my problem.